# How to attach keyboard and mouse to another screen?

Tags: x11, xorg, keyboard, mouse

By default, the X server would attach keyboard and mouse to display `0:0`, but how to change it to another screen such as `0:20`?

Comment: In X11 the number before the colon (`:`) is the display number. All screens (number after the colon (`:`) of this display share the same keyboards and pointing devices. Did you mean “another display, such as `20:0`”?